# C# Json SerializationException json to dataset

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, mono

I would like to deserialize Json to Dataset this way :

```
public class Equip : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string equipJson;

    void Start ()
    {
        equipJson = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + "/Resources/equip.json");
        DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(equipJson);
    }
}
```

But I get this error :

> SerializationException: No element named XmlSchema could be found.
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetValue
>   (string,System.Type)...

The json file :

```
    {"Common":[
{"id":"C_001","name":"Axe","cost":"3","text":"abc"},
{"id":"C_002","name":"Sword","cost":"4","text":"def"},
{"id":"C_003","name":"Helmet","cost":"5"}],
"Rare":[
{"id":"C_004","name":"Armor","cost":"6","text":"ghi"},
{"name":"Boots"},
{"id":"C_006","name":"Bow","cost":"7","text":"mno"}]}
```

Doing some researches, I think the problem is due to the variations inside the json, sometimes there's no "id" or "text" but I don't know how to fix this.

Thank you very much !

Comment: I tried your code, and it work for me.

Comment: Me too. Are you using the `System.Data.DataSet`?

Comment: What version of Json.NET are you using?

Comment: I use that in unity with monodevelop, that may be why it doesn't work.. I have the System.Data dll in the assets but that doesn't seems to be good. Thank you for your help, I'm gonna update that.